# How can i make specific styling according to my column name (pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

The data looks like the below

```
Code  Col1  Col2    col3   col4   col5  
0    123     5      66       1.7    7  
1    123      1     4        12     -8     
2    123      9      5     -7       0    
3    123      34.4    0     4.789   2
```

i should be able to ignore applying the style on some column(example in this case col1) doesn't have to be always col1 i should be able to ignore it by specifying the name of the column.

Not every column should have the same style, example for col 2 and 5 i want to color in green positive values and in red negative values however for col3 i want to color in purple values below 50 and yellow the rest

The actual dataset has dozens of columns which different conditions to each regarding the coloring code which is function of column name.

what i have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('Data.xls', sheet_name='test')

styler = df.style

def _color_red_or_green(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color


styler.applymap(_color_red_or_green)

styler.to_excel('Output.xlsx')
```

but this doesn't give me any way to specify column name although it did color all my data red or green, i tried to pass the column name as parameter for `_color_red_or_green`

```
for col in df.dtypes.items():
    styler.applymap(_color_red_or_green(col[0]))
```

and adjusted the function accordingly but then had an exception `TypeError: the first argument must be callable` on `styler.to_excel('Output.xlsx')` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From version 1.3.0, Pandas `applymap` accepts a `subset` parameter:

> subset : label, array-like, IndexSlice, optional
> A valid 2d input to DataFrame.loc[], or, in the case of a 1d input
> or single key, to DataFrame.loc[:, ] where the columns are prioritised, to limit data to *before* applying the function.

So, in order, for instance, to colorize "Col1" only in the Excel output file, you can modify your code like this:

```py
styler.applymap(_color_red_or_green, subset=["Col1"])
```

From there, you could define the following function:

```py
def colorize(df, cols):
    def _color_red_or_green(val):
        color = "red" if val < 0 else "green"
        return "color: %s" % color

    styler = df.style

    styler.applymap(_color_red_or_green, subset=cols)

    styler.to_excel("Output.xlsx")
```

And then call it with the dataframe and the columns of your choice:

```py
colorize(df, ["Col1", "col3"])
```

Which outputs an Excel file with both "Col1" en "col3" values painted as green.

Comment: i'm unsure how that would help me since the function _color_red_or_green would still have only 1 parameter and the column name is not provided as a parameter to that function meaning i can't put my logic based on the column name inside that function.(i debugged and notice that for that function only Value is visible as parameter) Kindly provide your edit to my code including function _color_red_or_green if i'm missing anything.

Comment: Not sure to fully understand how to help you, see my updated answer anyway.